# What's the difference between 'if you wish' and 'If you don't mind'?

Tags: differences

A friend sent me a message saying: *You can come and keep me company if you wish.* I thought: *You can come and keep me company if you don't mind* would have been more friendly. I'm I wrong?

Comment: Just a point of note “if you wish” in that instance is way more friendly than, “if you don’t mind”.

Comment: @jim I will have to apologize to my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you wish* roughly means the same as *If you would like to*, and is most often used when offering someone a favour.  On the other hand, *If you don't mind* roughly means the same as *If you don't have any problems with it*,  and is most often used when asking someone a favour.

In this sentence, it is not really whether he asks you for a favour (he is lonely, and wants you to come), or if he offers you for a favour (he thinks you are lonely, so he offers that you can come).

However, I think the first sentence with *If you wish* sounds more natural.

Comment: "If you don't mind" is also used as a bit of fake politeness, to provide an excuse for the recipient of an order to pretend the he or she has some say in the matter.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I've never thought of this. Now I understand better. Thanks!